# Mvc multiple "wildcard" route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a route using my kind of wildcard:

```
 [Route("{category}/{subcategory?}/{property?}")]  
 public ActionResult SubPage(string category, string subcategory, string property, int? type)
    {}
```

The problem is that I want to add another controller under an "Amp" folder

```
    [Route("amp/{category}/{subcategory?}/{property?}")]
    public ActionResult Amp(string category, string subcategory, string subSubCategory)
    {}
```

My router looks like this:

```
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Amp",
         url: "amp/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Amp", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This doesn’t work if the url is /amp/category1 due to that the url structure match both  url's

Comment: you would need to make the placeholders optional as well. You also seem to be mixing convention-based and attribute routing.

Comment: @Nkosi, can you please advice me how to make an placeholder option?